# R: Visualize Multiple Columns with their Sum

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with the following columns: `product_id`, ..., `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, ... etc. The p-columns only have **0 or 1** as their cell data.

I want a bar chart that sums up (or count) `p1`, `p2` etc. and shows each p-column as a bar with the value of the sum (with **ggplot**).

Additionally I want to fill the color by `product_id`.

It seems like reshaping the data in the long format could be helpful, but I still stuck.

Here's the minimal data set, already reshaped:

```
product_id <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
p1 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
p2 <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
p3 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)

df1 <- data.frame(product_id, p1, p2, p3)

df2 <- melt(df1, id.vars = "product_id", 
                  measure.vars = grep("^p[0-9]", names(df1), value = TRUE),
                  variable.name = "p",
                  value.name = "p-active")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood exactly what you want, but I'll give it a try:

I changed the reshaping a bit, because it is not a good idea to use `-`  in the name of a data frame column:

```
df2 <- melt(df1, id.vars = "product_id", 
                  measure.vars = grep("^p[0-9]", names(df1), value = TRUE),
                  variable.name = "p",
                  value.name = "p_active")
```

The next step is to sum up the values in `p_active` per value for `p`  and `product_id`:

```
library(dplyr)
df2_summed <- group_by(df2, product_id, p) %>%
              summarise(p_active_summed = sum(p_active))
```

And finally, I create the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2_summed, aes(x = p, y = p_active_summed, fill = as.factor(product_id))) + 
    geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it - was about to post almost identical code to this.

Comment: @AndrewHaynes Sorry about that. Still, I have been beaten by Roland when it comes to elegance...

Answer (score 4):

There are dozens of ggplot2 tutorials, but I'm feeling generous:

```
ggplot(df2, 
       #map columns to aesthetics:
       aes(x = p, y = `p-active`, 
                #important to use a factor for discrete values:
                fill = factor(product_id), 
                color = factor(product_id))) +
  #summarize data:
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, 
               #the geom:
               geom = "bar", 
               #positioning:
               position = "dodge")
```